# tor Onion Circuits

Tags: onion-routing

I'm a neub learning Tor relaying and bridges. I am currently operating a relay on a droplet. It has been up for 14 days and has all of the flags assigned to it. I use a Pi 3 with Raspbian and run NYX in putty to monitor the relay without problem.

The question: I wish to monitor the circuits that are created by bridges (if I understand correctly). How? I downloaded Onion Circuits, installed locally and all I get is "you are not in Tor" The window itself is just two small windows that are blank.

I know these things take time to formulate, but I
seriously doubt that is the problem.

I've obviously missed something, stumped on this one.

Thanks for any Help :-)

Adriann

Comment: I reviewed onion circuits and it is an app that was developed for Tails. I don't know how you are running it, but you might want to run it with torsocks to make sure that it sees the Tor network.

Comment: Thank you JSEvans!! My relay has torsocks set to 0 which means it's disabled. I know zilch on the subject of torsocks which I'm sure after some research, some answers will be taken care of. Is it a simple matter of enabling socks on the droplet or does torsocks have to be run locally?

Comment: torsocks is an application that is usually installed with tor. On raspbian, you can install it with `apt get install torsocks` and then run `torsocks onioncircuits`. I've never tried running it outside of Tails so I'm not sure if there is anything else you will need to do.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [onion circuits](https://git-tails.immerda.ch/onioncircuits/) uses the [ControlPort](https://github.com/torproject/tor/blob/9892cc3b12db4dc1e8cbffec8e18bb18cbd77d0f/src/config/torrc.sample.in#L57) to collect information on TOR circuits and streams.

Be sure that you have added (or uncommented) the `ControlPort 9051` line within your `torrc`.

This should allow for onion circuits to collect the required data.

Comment: Oooops! my control port is on 9050! Is there a configuration file for onion circuits?? - Adriann

Comment: I have not used that piece of software before but it looks like the only place it is specified is in the python3 executable by the name of onioncircuits.
The line is `int(os.environ.get('TOR_CONTROL_PORT', 9051))`
Changing this value should change the expected ControlPort